CrewAI SeleniumScrapingTool can´t initialize the Chrome Driver inside Docker container
I have a docker image as follows:
FROM python:3.12-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r ./requirements.txt
COPY ./app ./
ENV ENVIRONMENT prod
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["fastapi", "run", "main.py", "--port", "3000"]

And my requirements.txt:
fastapi==0.111.1
langchain==0.3.7
langchain-community==0.3.7
langchain-core==0.3.19
crewai==0.80.0
crewai-tools==0.14.0

And my python code that starts an CrewAI Agent and pass the SeleniumScrapingTool as a tool to him:
from crewai import Agent, Task, Crew, Process
from crewai_tools import SeleniumScrapingTool

chrome_options = {
                'args': [
                    '--no-sandbox',
                    '--headless',
                    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                    '--disable-gpu',
                    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                    '--disable-software-rasterizer',
                    '--disable-dbus',
                    '--disable-notifications',
                    '--disable-extensions',
                    '--disable-infobars'
                ],
                'service_args': ['--verbose'],  # For debugging
                'experimental_options': {
                    'excludeSwitches': ['enable-automation'],
                    'prefs': {
                        'profile.default_content_setting_values': {
                            'cookies': 1,
                            'images': 2,  # Don't load images for better performance
                            'plugins': 2,
                            'popups': 2,
                            'geolocation': 2,
                            'notifications': 2
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            tool = SeleniumScrapingTool(website_url='URL', chrome_options=chrome_options)

Agent(
       role=ROLE,
       goal=GOAL,
       backstory=BACKSTORY,
       tools=tool
     )

But somehow when i start my docker container it gives the following error trying to use the SeleniumScrapingTool:
2024-11-23 17:23:10 I encountered an error while trying to use the tool. This was the error: Message: Service /root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/131.0.6778.85/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

But when i try to run at my local environment (windows 11) it runs perfectly. Only insides the docker image the error occurs.
